# Is there a way to automatically convert a gradle project to ant?

Tags: java, gradle, ant, netbeans-8

I have a [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/release-notes.html) project that uses Java 1.8 to build and compile a WAR and Jar file.  When running the gradle wrapper initially, it downloads all the *.jar dependencies over the internet into a local cache that sits in my ~/.gradle directory.  The next time I run the gradle wrapper, it's much faster since all the dependencies have been downloaded.

Now I would like to convert this project into an [Ant](https://ant.apache.org) / [Netbeans](http://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/ide/overview-screencast.html) project (i.e. where I can open the project in Netbeans and click on the "Clean & Build" button and it invokes an ant build).  Is there an easy way to do this? Perhaps if I feed as input the "build.gradle" file into a converter program ?

What I am really asking is: How do I convert the "build.gradle" to Netbean's project.properties ?

Comment: Don't. Ant is bad. Gradle and Maven were created because Ant is bad. Netbeans is also bad. Use IntelliJ. The only reason to continue with your current plan is if you want to roleplay as a Java developer from 2003.

Comment: @Michael I fully agree, but I have the impression that some education institutions use Netbeans. That's why so many Netbeans related questions are still hitting SO.

Comment: Can't you import the gradle project into netbeans? At least it seams to be supported when creating a new project.